# Converting a char to gchar

Tags: c, gtk, char

So, heres the deal, I'm using GTK on this one.

I'm asking for Name on a `set_entry_text`. So the user enters his name and I save that variable as a char.

```
char *jugador1, *jugador2 ///they're in a structure

void obten_nombre (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer info)
{
  WIDGETS *elementos = (WIDGETS *)info;
  gchar *j1, *j2;

   j1=malloc(50 *sizeof(gchar));
  j2=malloc(50 *sizeof(gchar));
  strcpy(j1,gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY( elementos->entry_j1)));
  strcpy(j2,gtk_entry_get_text(GTK_ENTRY( elementos->entry_j2)));
  strcpy(elementos->jugador1, j1);
  elementos->jj1=j1;
  // strcpy(elementos->jugador2, j2);
  g_print("Jugador1: %s\n", elementos->jugador1);
   gtk_widget_hide_all(elementos->ventana_popup2);
   gtk_widget_show_all(elementos->ventana_principe);
}
```

There I'm making `elementos->jugador1` a `char` variable.

I'm making a cast:

```
gchar auxjugador1;
```

How can I make

```
auxjugador1 = elementos->jugador1
```

so I can do a

```
gtk_entry_set_text(GTK_ENTRY(elementos->nombre_jugador1),auxjugador1);
```

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`jugador1` is NOT a `char` variable.  It's a `char *` (a pointer).

You can't put a pointer into a `gchar`.

You can either make another pointer, and point it to the existing data, or declare an array large enough to hold a copy, then use `strcpy`.

Comment: Yes, I tried doing a strcpy(auxjugador1,jj1) both are gchar... Am I doing it right?

Comment: @drodri420: To use `strcpy`, you'll need to make `auxjugador` an array big enough to hold the string.  Like `gchar auxjugador[1000];`.